# TF message arrays

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish some sort of location data but in unknown quantities. I use some sort of vision algorithm to find items in scene I want to publish 0...n found items in single message. So I can compare this set to one found in next frame or message.

Vector3Stamped.msg looks mostly what I need but I change definition "Vector3 vector" to "Vector3[] vector".

Question is, if TF is able to handle the situation and provide conversion without hassle? As much I understand, TF knows some datatypes and provides easy conversion on them. Can it understand arrays? Current situation:

```
tonu@hp:~/TYROS/tyros_camera$ cat msg/Objects.msg 
Header header
Object[] object

tonu@hp:~/TYROS/tyros_camera$ cat msg/Object.msg 
geometry_msgs/Vector3 vector
float32 certainity
string type

tonu@hp:~/TYROS/tyros_camera$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10167/tf-message-arrays/) by [Tõnu Samuel](https://answers.ros.org/users/394/t%C3%B5nu-samuel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2011-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The standard TF methods do not support arrays of messages.  You can easily write a wrapper methods which has a for loop to do so.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2